# Jquery - Error message in Firefox developer tools: 'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I struggle with jQuery and I can't see what the problem is here. Any suggestions?

> **Error message in Firefox developer tools: 'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'**, in line 1.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
       if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
           $('#smoothup') .fadeOut();
       } else {
           $('#smoothup') .fadeIn();
       }
   });
   $('#smoothup').on('click', function(){
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
       return false;
       });
});
```

Comment: Were the line numbers in your code originally, or did you post the line numbers to demonstrate which one was `line 1`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your line numbers are embedded in the code. This causes the error you are receiving and most likely came from copying and pasting from a website. Line numbers should not be included in the source, as it causes the JavaScript parser to interpret them as code statements, thus producing your error. Remove them like so.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
       if ($(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
           $('#smoothup') .fadeOut();
       } else {
           $('#smoothup') .fadeIn();
       }
   });
   $('#smoothup').on('click', function(){
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast');
       return false;
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, would it work if you change

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

into

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```